# Carousel not sliding on bootstrap in different web servers

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website installed on two different servers. On the first web the Carousel works correctly but the second does not. The problem is that in the second web the Carousel does not slide.

WEB 1: http://us.insidecraft.com/pruebas2/
WEB 2: https://www.insidecraft.com/

The two pages contain the same code. The web is hosted on different web servers in one works and not in another.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: you need to update what code you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JS call to HTTPS. Also fix the other console errors. jQuery and bootstrap are hitting 404s.

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js